# What does the new keyword "yield" mean in Java 13?

Tags: java, switch-statement, yield, java-13

Java 13 introduced the `yield` keyword for the `switch` expressions.

How can I use it and what's the difference between a default `return` or `break` value?

Comment: It is only ever used to specify a return value from inside a [`switch` statement](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/java-enhanced-switch/). It is different to a `return` as it _yields_ from a statement as opposed to _returns_ from a method.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Java 12 used `break <value>`, the `return <value>` was iirc only considered, but never part of a released version.

Comment: It is worth noting that `yield` is not a keyword. `Thread` has a `yield()` method that is there to stay, and you can name any of your vairables, fields, methods or labels `yield` long as your namespace allows it.

Comment: @AhmadShahwan Since Java 13, `yield` is a special keyword that can still be used as a method name, as long as you specify the class/instance reference as well. In other words, calling Thread.yield() still works fine, but yield() within a Thread run() method no longer does.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### Q&A

> How can I use it?

1. With arrow labels when a full block is needed:

   ```
   int value = switch (greeting) {
       case "hi" -> {
           System.out.println("I am not just yielding!");
           yield 1;
       }
       case "hello" -> {
           System.out.println("Me too.");
           yield 2;
       }
       default -> {
           System.out.println("OK");
           yield -1;
       }
   };
   ```
2. With traditional blocks:

   ```
   int value = switch (greeting) {
       case "hi":
           System.out.println("I am not just yielding!");
           yield 1;
       case "hello":
           System.out.println("Me too.");
           yield 2;
       default:
           System.out.println("OK");
           yield -1;
   };
   ```

> What's the difference to a default return?

A `return` statement returns control to **the invoker of a method** ([§8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4), [§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)) or **constructor** ([§8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8), [§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-15.9)) while a `yield` statement transfers control by **causing an enclosing `switch` expression** to produce a specified value.

> What's the difference to a break value?

The `break` with value statement is dropped in favour of a `yield` statement.

### Specification

There is [Specification for JEP 354](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/preview/switch-expressions.html) attached to [the JLS 13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/index.html) which sums up everything we need to know about the new `switch`. Note that it wasn't merged into the language specification because it's still [a preview feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12) and, thus, not yet a permanent part of the language.

> A `yield` statement transfers control by causing an enclosing `switch` expression to produce a specified value.
>
> ```
> YieldStatement:
>     yield Expression;
> ```
>
> A `yield` statement attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing switch expression; this expression, which is called *the yield target*, then immediately completes normally and the value of the `Expression` becomes the value of the `switch` expression.
>
> - It is a compile-time error if a `yield` statement has no yield target.
> - It is a compile-time error if the `yield` target contains any method, constructor, initializer, or lambda expression that encloses the yield statement.
> - It is a compile-time error if the `Expression` of a `yield` statement is void (15.1).
>
> Execution of a `yield` statement first evaluates the `Expression`. If the evaluation of the `Expression` completes abruptly for some reason, then the `yield` statement completes abruptly for that reason. If evaluation of the `Expression` completes normally, producing a value `V`, then the `yield` statement completes abruptly, the reason being a yield with value `V`.

Answer (score 21):

As part of JEP 354 (Java 13), you can [yield](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) value in switch (optionally assign it to variable)

> yield statement to yield a value, which becomes the value of the enclosing switch expression.
>
> ```
> int j = switch (day) {
>     case MONDAY  -> 0;
>     case TUESDAY -> 1;
>     default      -> {
>         int k = day.toString().length();
>         int result = f(k);
>         yield result;
>     }
> };
> ```

I think your confusion is with [JEP 325](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) on Java 12 that use break to return value:

> we have extended the break statement to take an argument, which becomes the value of the enclosing switch expression.
>
> ```
> int j = switch (day) {
>      case MONDAY  -> 0;
>      case TUESDAY -> 1;
>      default      -> {
>          int k = day.toString().length();
>          int result = f(k);
>          break result;
> ```

In addition, you can even use [lambda syntax](https://blog.codefx.org/java/switch-expressions/)

> ```
> boolean result = switch (ternaryBool) {
>     case TRUE -> true;
>     case FALSE -> false;
>     case FILE_NOT_FOUND -> throw new UncheckedIOException(
>         "This is ridiculous!",
>         new FileNotFoundException());
>     // as we'll see in "Exhaustiveness", `default` is not necessary
>     default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seriously?! ");
> };
> ```
>
> With switch expressions, the entire switch block "gets a value" that can then be assigned; you can use a lambda-style syntax
>
> While Java 12 introduces and 13 refines switch expressions, they do so as a preview language feature. That means (a) it can still change over the next few releases (as it did between 12 and 13) and (b) it needs to be unlocked, at compile time and run time, with the new command line option --enable-preview. Then **keep in mind that this isn’t the endgame for switch – it’s just a step on the way to full pattern matching.**

Comment: Anyone know why this was changed from JDK 12? The JEP doesn't give much insight into why `yield` was chosen over `break`.

Comment: @Druckles it seems a choice to separate *break* for breaking switch and *yield* for returning value, see https://metebalci.com/blog/what-is-new-in-java-13/#jep-354-switch-expressions-preview also using break can move to label see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/preview/switch-expressions.html#jep354-14.21

Comment: @Druckles It was changed because, in our research with users, people found the overloading of `break` confusing.

Comment: @BrianGoetz it *is* confusing. Though, I liked the analogy with the two forms of `return` mentioned [here](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325)

Comment: return@ in Kotlin is much better solution, than new keyword...

Answer (score 6):

`yield` marks value to be returned from a switch branch. It terminates the switch expression, you don't need to have break after it.

From [doc](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354)

> The two statements, break (with or without a label) and yield,
>   facilitate easy disambiguation between switch statements and switch
>   expressions: a switch statement but not a switch expression can be the
>   target of a break statement; and a switch expression but not a switch
>   statement can be the target of a yield statement.

It also provides, `NullPointerException` Safety,

```
String message = switch (errorCode) {
    case 404:
        yield "Not found!";
    case 500:
        yield "Internal server error!";
    // No default
};
```

This will result in,

> the switch expression does not cover all possible input values

Answer (score 1):

break replace with yield in java 13. This is one of the preview feature defined in java 13.in Java 12, we can use break to return a value from a switch. But in java 13 yield use for the return value from switch expression.

[In Java 13 break replace by yield](http://sandny.com/2019/11/17/java-13-switch-expressions/),

```
String number = switch (number) {
    case 1:
        yield "one";
    case 2:
        yield "two";
    default:
        yield "Zero";
}
```

Arrow syntax is still supported in Java 13.

```
String number = switch (number) {
    case 1 -> "one";
    case 2 -> "two";
    default -> "Zero";
}
```

Comment: `yield` does not replace `break`, it adds different functionality.